# php array index giving errors

Tags: php, arrays

I have created a php array, and var dumped it.
In the var dump, I can see a item, but when I try to access that Item, it gives a php error. Here is the var_dump.

```
array(16) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "Title"
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "Title"
    [3]=>
    string(15) "String"
    ["seller"]=>
    string(15) "String"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["category"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [5]=>
    string(347) "String"
    ["description"]=>
    string(347) "String"
    [6]=>
    string(69) "String"
    ["img"]=>
    string(69) "String"
    [7]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["stock"]=>
    string(1) "0"
}
```

This piece of code is giving the error. Any help would be nice.

```
$array["img"]
```

Error Log:

```
[02-Jul-2017 13:40:30 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: img in myWebPage on line 98
[02-Jul-2017 13:40:30 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: img in myWebPage on line 100
```

Code:

```
var_dump($product);
echo $product["img"];
echo '<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="'.$product["img"].'" alt="'.$product["name"].'" style="height: 200px;">
        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">'.$product["name"].'</h4>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</a>
        </div>
    </div>';
// The array is stored in product.
```

Comment: What is name of your array(name of array varieble)? and what is the error?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Can you add more of the code you are using?

Comment: Try $array[0]["img"] , undefined index means you are not specifying the index of the element hence [0]

Comment: How did you create that aarray. It looks wrong where it says `["img"]=> string(69) "String"`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just hid some of the private content

Comment: @RedCrusador It worked! Mind explaining how you found it out?

Comment: Is `6` accessible?

Comment: Just from memory. But for future reference use php.net , here is the page for arrays http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Comment: @RedCrusador, Thanks for the help! Please post that as a answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @KingCoder11 thanks , glad you found it useful , posted as answer to help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $array[0]["img"] , undefined index means you are not specifying the index of the element hence [0]

For future reference use php.net , here is the page for arrays http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php